# Why running an executable through cmd does not invoke system() call?

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, clion

I have a small piece of C code as below. I have tried to run it using 2 methods.

1) With Clion using Cygwin64 environment

2) With command prompt (in this case, I have to move a cygwin1.dll to the same folder with the executable).

My code need to call the system() function to run some cmd command.

If i tried the 1st method, the code works flawlessly. However, when using the 2nd method, the  system() call seems to be doing exactly nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fp=fopen("run.bat", "w+");
    fprintf(fp,"dir > result.txt\n");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Before calling System\n");
    system("cmd.exe /c run.bat");
    if(access("result.txt",F_OK)==0){
        printf("Run completed!\n");
    }
    printf("After calling System\n");

}
```

What I get for doing with 1 is the line "Run completed!" got [printed out normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I82lA.png).

However, with 2, no "result.txt" was created, and thus the "Run completed!" line [never appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxXrH.png).

Now I need my executable to be executable in cmd to be of any use. So can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check the result of `fopen`? Of `system`?

Comment: There is a run.bat file. It just does not execute, so I am pretty sure it was the problem with system(). I tried even basic command like cls, and it does not work.

Comment: I'm guessing it tries to run the command with `/bin/sh` and that is not available when running from a normal cmd console window. Does it work if you run it from a Cygwin bash terminal window?

Comment: Cygwin terminal works fine :D But I need to carry this executable to other PC (well, not this piece of code but something bigger), and there is just no Cygwind Terminal there.

Comment: If you need to run on a system without a Cygwin environment, then you should think carefully about using Cygwin build tools. Microsoft's C compiler is not one that I usually recommend, but I do expect that building with that compiler will produce an executable in which the `system()` function works as you want when the program runs in a native Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, but not in a very convenient way.

I have to download Microsoft Visual Studio, and run Clion through with VS environment, and fix certain compatibility issue.

I suppose while most of the function work fine, `system()` is an exception. This command is not very widely used anyway, but be aware while using it on Windows with some Linux compiler.