# How to execute batch (.bat) file in Windows with C

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, cygwin, clion

I need to program something with C that can execute .bat file on Windows.

Naturally, the `system()` function should come to mind. However, there is a [huge issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576567/why-running-an-executable-through-cmd-does-not-invoke-system-call). Basically, the function `system()` does not get executed.

Things I tried:

1) Compile and run my code from Cygwin terminal does work, however, this is not really viable because I need to move my program to different PC, and having to install Cywind in every single one of then is just a bad idea.

2) I have tried to cd to `C:\Windows\System32\` and still does not work.

3) I have tried with `popen()`, and still not working.

4) Could it be because of the compiler I am using: Cywin64 on CLion? But even if I changed the environment to Windows Subsystem for Linux, it still does NOT work!

At this point, i have lost many brain cell and have pretty much given up.

After trying everything, I think the reason is either `system()` would tried to run the command from `/bin/sh`, which is not available when running from a normal cmd console window, or `system()` is just outright broken. Also, not only running batch, pretty much any other cmd command would not work. Heck, even `ls` will not work.

Googling does not help at all.

All I really want is to execute .bat file inside a C program. Basically it. Any advice?

Comment: You have to locate the batch file in the working directory of the executable, or specify the path to the batch file, or add the known location of the batch file in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Well, I definitey have but the .bat file to the same folder with the exe. Also, pretty much any cmd command will not work.

Comment: You realize that `ls` is a Linux shell command, and won't work on Windows regardless? (outside of Cygwin)

Comment: I going to surmise that the batch file also contains Linux-specific commands. It's probably running, it just returns with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ShellExecute()` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea

Answer (score 0):

`ShellExecute()` does not work. Same thing happened with `System()`.

My solution is to download Microsoft Visual Studio, and run Clion through with VS environment (need to fix certain compatibility issue).